# redirect http request URI in mozilla Addon Builder

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

I defined a `http-on-modify-request` observer in Mozilla's Addon Builder, and want to redirect requests (change `subject.URI.spec`), but Firefox complains about:

```
Error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 2536, in null
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 2344, in null
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 2988, in wi
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 1756, in ti
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 1231, in Ji
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 3366, in Ri
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 2381, in Di
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 2956, in Ni
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 3366, in DHb
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 3340, in oHb
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 1869, in Eic
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 3285, in BS
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 3362, in _Jb
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 3054, in _Bb
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 2020, in dJb
  File "http://chrome.angrybirds.com/", line 2889, in fJb
  File "resource://jid0-[snipped id]-api-utils-lib/observer-service.js", line 176, in null
    this.callback(subject, data);
  File "resource://jid0-[snipped id]-moddedbirds-url-rewriter-lib/main.js", line 11, in null
    if(endsWith(s.URI.spec,search)) s.URI.spec=replace;
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004004 (NS_ERROR_ABORT)
  [nsIURI.spec]"  nsresult: "0x80004004 (NS_ERROR_ABORT)" location: "JS frame
  :: resource://jid0-[snipped id]-api-utils-lib/securable-module.js
  -> resource://jid0-[snipped id]-moddedbirds-url-rewriter-lib/main.js ::
  <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 11"  data: no]
```

Why doesn't it work?

Maybe I can't use the `http-on-modify-request` observer to rewrite URIs?

How do I do that?

Comment: Not a full solution, either, but maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205672/modify-url-before-loading-page-in-firefox/5207141#5207141

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox extension: Cancel requests and emit fake responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222577/firefox-extension-cancel-requests-and-emit-fake-responses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [nsIChannel docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannel) say "The URI corresponding to the channel. Its value is immutable. Read only." And the immutable check seems to indeed return NS_ERROR_ABORT ([source](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/src/nsStandardURL.cpp#85)).

Unfortunately for you, this guy ( [Redirecting Request (nsiHttpChannel?) in Firefox Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237108/redirecting-request-nsihttpchannel-in-firefox-extensions) ) didn't post the solution he found, also this question is asked [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2230883) and [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2354933) on mozillazine.

The best idea I have is too much work for this: to try [nsITraceableChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsITraceableChannel). Wladimir [here](http://adblockplus.org/blog/the-wrong-way-to-deal-with-privacy-concerns) has an idea to "make all the necessary calls to nsIChannel.notificationCallbacks and cancel the request after that". [Bug 286159](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286159) has some discussion on this (there didn't seem to be a way to do this cleanly in 2005).

Since this is a recurring question, it would be great if you got a confirmation from a [Necko peer](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Modules/All#Core), then documented it on MDC.

Comment: reading the pages you referenced, it seems to be impossible until the plugin api gets changed? sad. have to stay with proxies then.

Comment: @nonchip: hard, not impossible. I mentioned some things you could try, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205672/modify-url-before-loading-page-in-firefox/ references the code in HTTPS everywhere.

Comment: I actually tried to implement the solution here, it even sort of worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222577/firefox-extension-cancel-requests-and-emit-fake-responses/7226550#7226550

Comment: @WladimirPalant your code redirects webpages, but i need to redirect ajax requests and img.src="..."-requests.

Comment: @Nickolay HTTPSeverywhere also only works on web pages. catching onLoad and navigating to another URI works, but i need more :-/ i think i'll stay with proxies.